Why Are There Different Definitions of "Period" and "Fundamental Period" in Mathematical Literature?
In some references like Thomas’ Calculus, "period" is defined as follows:

A function $f(x)$ is periodic if there is a positive number $p$ such that $f(x+p)=f(x)$ for every value of $x$. The smallest such value of $p$ is the period of $f$.

However, in other references, such as the Wikipedia article on periodic functions, the definition is slightly different:

A function $f$ is said to be periodic if, for some nonzero constant $P$, it is the case that $f(x+P)=f(x)$ for all values of $x$ in the domain. A nonzero constant $P$ for which this is the case is called a period of the function. If there exists a least positive constant $P$ with this property, it is called the fundamental period.

These definitions seem to differ in two significant ways:

Thomas’ Calculus only mentions positive periods, while other sources allow for any nonzero constant period.
The term "fundamental period" is explicitly mentioned in some references but omitted in others and the term "period" is used instead.

Given that "period" is a fundamental concept in mathematics, especially in trigonometry and Fourier analysis, I think such differences are strange. While it is evident that, for most practical purposes, these variations do not impact how we study periodic functions or their properties, my question delves deeper:

Why do such discrepancies exist in the first place? Is this simply a matter of preference or style between authors, or is there a historical or conceptual reason behind these differing definitions and terms, such as differences in mathematical contexts? How does this lack of standardization arise and persist for such a widely used concept in mathematics?

Additionally, are such differences in definitions and terminology common for other core mathematical concepts? If so, what does this tell us about the nature of mathematical communication and pedagogy?



The issue is that there exist functions which are periodic but do not have smallest periods, e.g. the Dirichlet function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function), or more simply any constant function. So they have "periods" but don't have "a period," and to make this distinction more precise the term "fundamental period" can be used. More conceptually, the issue is that "period" really refers not to a number but to a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.

@QiaochuYuan: You might consider making that a brief answer (possibly community wiki?).
